# Invalid parameter number error on local machine

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I keep getting this error in my local machine, I don't get this error on a server or any other machine, I have removed and reinstalled xampp, I have migrated fresh DB and inserted values again, still the same error, I can't seem to find what's wrong.

**Error:**

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: SELECT h.* FROM huts_models h WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM hut_bookings hb WHERE hb.Huts_Selected = h.id AND (('16/09/2021' >= hb.Check_in_date AND '16/09/2021' <= hb.Check_out_date) OR ('16/09/2021' <= hb.Check_in_date AND '08/09/2021' >= hb.Check_in_date))))

**Stack Trace:**
https://flareapp.io/share/LPlg6Nnm

This is what I have in my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\HutsModel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class DhanoltiEcoHuts extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $flag = false;
        $huts = HutsModel::where('Status', '=', 'Available')->paginate(8);
        return view('front-end.pages.booking.dhanolti-eco-huts', compact('huts', 'flag'));
    }

    public function searchRooms()
    {
        $flag = true;
        $checkin = request()->deh3_checkin;
        $checkout = request()->deh3_checkout;
        $huts = DB::select("SELECT h.* FROM huts_models h WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM hut_bookings hb WHERE hb.Huts_Selected = h.id AND (('$checkin' >= hb.Check_in_date AND '$checkin' <= hb.Check_out_date) OR ('$checkin' <= hb.Check_in_date AND '$checkout' >= hb.Check_in_date)))", [1]);
        return view('front-end.pages.booking.dhanolti-eco-huts', compact('huts', 'flag'));
    }
}
```

This is the JS code used to get the date format:

```
$("#deh3_checkin")
    .datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        startDate: new Date()
    }).on("hide", function (ev) {
        // console.log("ev", ev)
        var date2 = $("#deh3_checkin").datepicker("getDate");
        // console.log(date2)
        date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 2);

        $("#deh3_checkout").datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            startDate: $("#deh3_checkin").datepicker("getDate"),
            endDate: date2
        });
        $("#deh3_checkout").datepicker("update");
    });

$("#deh3_checkout").datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    startDate: new Date()
});
```

This is what I have in the form in my view:

```
<input type="text" class="btn-default datepicker custom_Check_in_date"
 placeholder="Check In" name="deh3_checkin" id="deh3_checkin">
  
<input type="text" class="btn-default datepicker custom_Check_out_date"
placeholder="Check Out" name="deh3_checkout" id="deh3_checkout">
```

Comment: May I ask, are you actually using `DD/MM/YYYY` date format? Because if you do, that would make the column datatype as probably `varchar` and unless you convert the date value to standard date format, you can't expect something like this `'16/09/2021' >= hb.Check_in_date` will return correct results. Refer [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9259cd081f3b0602d7e6c6bdaef68101)

Comment: Thanks for your response, yes I am using `dd/mm/yyyy` format, and the column data type is also set to `varchar(191)`. I have also edited my question and added the `js` and the `view`.

Comment: If like that, in order for you to compare/filter dates in MySQL using date manipulation functions, you must use standard date format. I know this i not the issue stated in your question but I think it's important to address it since in date form, the date `31/07/2021` is earlier than `01/08/2021` but in `varchar`, it will be the opposite.

Comment: `DB:select(" ... ", [1]);` - but there are no placeholders in the query that use that parameter `[1]`.  I'm voting to close this as a simple typo.

Comment: @FaNo_FN I changed it to standard date format it still has no effect.

Comment: If you're telling me that after you change the date format, the error is still appear then, yes, of course the error still appear. The point I was making is non-related to the error at all. I'm just addressing that MySQL will not recognize `dd/mm/yyyy` as date, therefore directly using it in your query comparisons/filter returns incorrect results. Have you inspect the part mentioned in @Don'tPanic comment?

Comment: Yes I am getting the parameters from `$checkin` and `$checkout`, from the JS, to be clear this code is running on other machines and I am getting the desired result, I don't know why this is happening on my machine.

Comment: It does not look like you saw my comment?  What is `[1]`?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, you are right, it's a typo, my bad, its resolved now. Thanks for your help :)